# Unable to connect to IPv6 from Windows 8.1 via OpenWRT router

Tags: networking, ipv6

I'm new to Ipv6 and trying to learn it. So, I decided to use 6to4 tunneling from Hurricane Electric in my OpenWRT router since my ISP does not provide IPv6. It work perfectly in my router. But when I try `ping ipv6.google.com` it in my Windows 8.1, it failed with `Destination host unreachable.` with the following output of the `tcpdump` in the router:

```
13:52:39.648512 IP6 2001:470:XX:XXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX > ff02::1:ff21:c98e: ICMP6, neighbor solicitation, who has fe80::109c:e1ff:fe21:c98e, length 32
13:52:40.234465 IP6 2001:470:XX:XXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX > ff02::1:ff21:c98e: ICMP6, neighbor solicitation, who has fe80::109c:e1ff:fe21:c98e, length 32
13:52:41.234511 IP6 2001:470:XX:XXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX > ff02::1:ff21:c98e: ICMP6, neighbor solicitation, who has fe80::109c:e1ff:fe21:c98e, length 32
13:52:43.245871 IP6 2001:470:XX:XXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX > ff02::1:ff21:c98e: ICMP6, neighbor solicitation, who has fe80::109c:e1ff:fe21:c98e, length 32
```

The address `2001:470:XX:XXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX` is my Windows 8 as show in `Temporary IPv6 Address` in the NIC status. And `fe80::109c:e1ff:fe21:c98e` is my router link local address.

My router can ping Windows 8 with link local address. But Windows 8 cannot ping router with link local address.

Comment: How did you configure your OpenWrt router? And which _version_ of OpenWrt do you have?